# Save the RecurrenceRule of a event to CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5, icalendar

I am trying to save a RecurrenceRule of a event in my application. I am unable to frame the schema of the table. Please suggest what can be the Structure of table.

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to save it? As a property while the app is running? As a user default to be accessed upon next launch? Or in a database?

Comment: @Wienke : I want to store in Core Data. 
Right now i have Events Table whose schema is Events(Title, StartDate, EndDate, Id, Location, Description), Now my doubt is how to add Recurrence Rule to the Event. i.e., the Schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  calendarIdentifier  String
  daysOfTheMonth  relationship
  daysOfTheWeek  relationship
  daysOfTheYear  relationship
  firstDayOfTheWeek  Integer16
  frequency  Integer16
  interval  Integer16
  monthsOfTheYear  relationship
  recurrenceEnd  Date
  setPositions  relationship
  weeksOfTheYear  relationship
```

You should make a structure for the EKRecurrenceRule Class Reference.
Arrays will be relationships to according entities.
For ex.: daysOfTheWeek will be relationship to entity WeekDays, where you'll store days in property day as Integer16.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for ur answer. I am about to sync google Calendar events to my application. Google supports custom recurrence patterns (Such as Every monday, tuesday for 40 occurrences etc..). How can we store these type of Recurrence Rules? Do u think the above schema is enough for handling these type of patterns?